# Searching array index for number of occurances over a certain value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Thanks Jonathan Kuhn, I have updated this thread to reflect your suggestions.

I have the following array it is simply named $array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10213
            [branch] => 1
            [parent] => 10183
            [age] => 53
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10230
            [branch] => 1
            [parent] => 10213
            [age] => 22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10232
            [branch] => 1
            [parent] => 10213
            [age] => 17
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10234
            [branch] => 1
            [parent] => 10232
            [age] => 6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10223
            [branch] => 2
            [parent] => 10183
            [age] => 31
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10231
            [branch] => 3
            [parent] => 10183
            [age] => 19
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10260
            [branch] => 3
            [parent] => 10231
            [age] => 22
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10261
            [branch] => 3
            [parent] => 10231
            [age] => 16
        )
)
```

[branch] represents the original children of the person on the top of the family tree.

So for example I want to loop through and to be able to search $array for the total number of all people over the age of "21" who are also in [branch] => 1. etc

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you don't have a fixed depth, you will probably need to use recursion to count your values. You would almost be better off storing values under their id in a simple 2d array and then looping/counting that. Would make this much easier.

Comment: I updated my original code to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), apply your criteria and get the size of the resulting array:

```
$foo = array_filter($array, function($a) {
    return $a["age"] > 21 && $a["branch"] == 1;
});

echo(count($foo));
```

Comment: Ah nice and simple, I thought up this method as I was eating so thought I would paste it as well, but yours is much more improved and I will use it!

Comment: Nice, feel free to accept the answer if it helped you! @Mike

Comment: First time posting here, didn't realize that was there! Thanks!